# Getting issue while edit record in Django Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

*I Everyone i am getting issue while edit record based on problem id, only problem record show automatically chatquestion and option record not show automatically, maybe my ORM is wrong
somewhere, even when i save record getting error, please help me out. this is crud operation i have done list and add record but that is also complex if anyone can do simple its more helpful for me.. Thanyou.*

**models.py** *-this is all 3 models.*

```
class Problem(models.Model):
    Language = models.IntegerField(choices=Language_CHOICE, default=1)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type
        

class ChatQuestion(models.Model):
    question = RichTextField(null=True, blank=True)
    problem_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Problem,
        models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Problem',
    )
    sub_problem_id = models.ForeignKey(
        SubProblem,
        models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Sub Problem',
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question


class Option(models.Model):
    option_type = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    question_id = models.ForeignKey(
        ChatQuestion,
        models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Question',
    )
    problem=models.ForeignKey(
        Problem,
        models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Problem',
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    next_question_id = models.ForeignKey(ChatQuestion, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,
                                         related_name='next_question')
```

**forms.py**

```
class Editchatbot(forms.Form):
    problem=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Problem.objects.all(), required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control select2'}))
    question=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ChatQuestion.objects.all(), required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control select2'}))
    option=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Option.objects.all(), required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control select2'}))
    class Meta:
        fields=['problem','question','option']
```

**views.py**

```
def edit_chatbot(request,id=None):
    problem=Problem.objects.get(pk=id)
    question=ChatQuestion.objects.filter(problem_id=id)
    option=Option.objects.filter(question_id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Editchatbot(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            problem=form.cleaned_data['problem']
            question=form.cleaned_data['question']
            option=form.cleaned_data['option']
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,'successfully!')
            return redirect('/fleet/chatbot_list')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Please correct following',form.errors)
    else:
        form = Editchatbot(initial={'problem':problem,'question':question,'option':option})
    context = {
        'menu_management': 'active',
        'chatbot': 'active',
        'form': form,
        'question':question,
        'option':option
    }
    return render(request, "chatbot/edit_chatbot.html", context=context)
```

**output error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\HI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\20_jan_2022_everest\everest_jarvis\fleet\views.py", line 4129, in edit_chatbot
    form.save()
AttributeError: 'Editchatbot' object has no attribute 'save'
ERROR "POST /fleet/chatbot/edit/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 79813
```

Answer (score 0):

***Answer to initial error***

Change these three lines form using `changed_data` to using `cleaned_data`.

`changed_data` is a list that contains the names of the fields that have changes, it does not contain the changes themselves.  `cleaned_data` stored the data after validation. See the [Checking which form data has changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#checking-which-form-data-has-changed) docs for more

```
problem=form.cleaned_data['problem']
question=form.cleaned_data['question']
option=form.cleaned_data['option']
```

***Answer to 2nd error - no save method***

Your form should extend from `forms.ModelForm` rather than `form.Form`.  The former allow you to build database-driven forms ([see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/)) whereas the latter as you are currently using allows you to create forms that are not associated with models ([see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/))

You may also find this reference site useful [Classy Django Forms](https://cdf.9vo.lt/) it's an extremely useful reference site and works in a similar way to the more commonly used [Class Class-Baed Views](https://ccbv.co.uk/) reference site

***Update 3 - Based on reply***

I admit I looked more at your error than the what you were doing. I see now that you using multiple models within one form. So one approach would be to keep using the forms.Form and then add a save method yourself that you can call and write custom logic to save to each model. Another option would be use a model form using one model via it's meta, add the other fields as custom ones, overload the save method to save the fist model and then add your own logic to save the other models.

Comment: sorry my mistake but when i updated record getting, output error is mentioned on code.

Comment: I've updated my reply based on your updated question. You're using forms.Form, switch that to use forms.ModelForm then you'll be using a model form which means the save method will be available

Comment: so how can join these model in model form

Comment: Ah okay I admit I looked more at your error than the what you were doing. I see now that you using multiple models within one form. So one approach would be to keep using the forms.Form and then add a save method yourself that you can call and write custom logic to save to each model. Another option would be use a model form using one model via it's meta, add the other fields as custom ones, overload the save method to save the fist model and then add your own logic to save the other models.

Comment: i have tied to solve this create 3 modelForm and Edit Record based on Problem id but in Chatquestion table one problem id repeated multiple time, if i edit record based on problem id so all record edit which is stored on chatquestion table, how can solve this problem

Comment: So are you looking at show all the ChatQuestion records that relate to the Problem record you are trying to edit at once? If you are then you need to use a formset, or modelformset, so that you can show all of the ChatQuestions. If you are only trying to show chat question then you need to make the chat question the record you load from  the view so that just show that one question. By loading that object you'll have the associated problem and can use the related_on name or the option_set but it depends on what you actually want to show to the user